# Tab Bar at top of HTML body

Tags: html, browser, hyperlink, tabs, icons

In my google account, for example, when I click their youtube icon, it opens youtube in a browser tab. Is it allowable/possible to have icons open as tab of a tab bar within the html body, directly below the browser bar, having the code of the site of whatever icon is clicked begin a few lines lower?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? i cant seem to understand your question

Comment: See how stack overflow has that horizontal bar at the top? Could they link you to another website and keep their horizontal bar there?

Comment: In other words, you could click stack overflows's horizontal bar to return back instead of re-entering it.

Comment: You mean like having this bar present while all the other page is google/youtube/facebook/etc?

Comment: or just having a link in the bar that will open another tab of these sites?

Comment: I will try to answer your question, accept it if it fits to your question, or make it clear if it don't :)

Comment: Somewhat of both I think. A link in the bar that will open the other page, google/youtube/facebook ect but keep the bar in tact. So you would click the youtube icon that stackoverflow offers in the body of its website, it then puts the youtube icon in the bar and loads youtube below the bar, and then obviously it would have the "stackoverflow" icon in the bar too so you can return to it.

Answer (score 0):

Having a navigation bar on the top of your page is as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Awesome NavBar</a>
</nav>
```

If you meant having links to other pages openning in a new tab in your browser there is an attribute called `target` to an `<a>` element, if you give it the value `_blank` it opens the link in a new tab

So your navbar should look something like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Awesome NavBar</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="youtube.com" target="_blank">Youtube</a>
            <a href="google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
            <a href="facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope that answers your question, let me know if it doesn't :)

### EDIT:

If you're trying to achieve these sites displayed within your site and keep the bar presented above you might want to take a look at [iframe documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) which basically is having another document (html page) within yours